# LInux vi editor,how to replace special character?

Tags: linux, vi

I wrote some text in vi editor,such as

```
xxx
xxx.g/gasd/ga
gasdj\gqweg/fsda
fg-cgdohd
```

now I want to replace the "/g" to "abc"
how to escape it
I wrote

```
:%s/'/g'/abc/g
```

in command line,it's no working,how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any character, not just a slash, in your search & replace:

```
%s:/g:abc:g
```

Comment: if I want to replace ":abc" to"abc",How to do it?

Comment: Again, you can use **any** character; colon was just an example. So you could do `%s|:abc|abc|g` or you could go back to a slash `$s/:abc/abc/g`

Comment: If I edit some file,and find that is "readonly" when I "wq" ,How could I chmod it with no quit vi editor?

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question. These are very basic questions, though; try google first.